# 3/4 Icon in the status bar. What is that?

Tags: mac, icon

[image: 3/4]

Can you help me understand what application put [image] icon in the status bar ? it get disappears when Im trying to click on it to get the context menu.

Thank you !

[image: 3/4]

Comment: Do you have an app that tracks the moon phases?

Answer (score 1):

That was "Habitify" app badge , application that track habits.

[image: habitify]